# Namespaces and External Librairies in PHP5.3 - Doctrine integration

Tags: php, namespaces, doctrine, integration

I want to integrate Doctrine in a freshly build PHP5 framework. I am using namespaces. The librairy is organised in maps :

- app (controllers, blocks, actions, ...)
- ext (external librairies)
- sys (kernel and route objects).

Now I want to integrate Doctrine which is in map ext.

In the calling class I have :

```
namespace app\example;
use ext\Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
```

To make this work I need to change every namespace reference in Doctrine to e.g. :

```
namespace ext\Doctrine\DBAL;
use ext\Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
```

In my opinion this is a very unelegant solution.

Question : 
Is there a way to not change Doctrine namespaces ? 
Is there a better strategy to deal with external librairies ?

Comment: You normally do that mapping not via the concrete namespace definitions but telling the (auto)loader where to find doctrine. However, you didn't ask anything specific, you are just describing where you hit the wall. I would question your overall processing instead and just say, it looks like that you're doing things wrong (in a good meaning, please don't feel offended, just pointing out you should look for alternative ways how to do what you want to do).

Comment: I'm not offended, no worries. I know I am missing something.  It is a correct alternative indeed I'm looking for. I will look into the autoloader strategy. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

The better strategy is to use the namespace provided by the library. Changing this would be highly unusual.

I'm guessing your main problem is actually because of autoloading. Remember that the namespace and the directory does not have to be identical.

Just make your autoloader a bit smarter to look for external libraries in ext. You can keep a small registry of namespaces that you can find there.

Better yet, start using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: This is actually what I did. In the autoloader all files not starting with app, ext or sys get a prefix ext/. use Doctrine\Something + new Something()  will lead to a ext/Doctrine/Something.php autoload. The composer strategy is something I will consider later. Thank you !